# Uniform Convergence Preserves Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Briefly, the definitions of point-wise convergence (PWC) and uniform convergence (UC) for a sequence of functions $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ in my mind are recorded as

\begin{align*}
&\text{Point Wise Convergent on $[a,b]$} \iff \\ 
&\forall x\in [a,b]\,\forall\epsilon\gt0\,\exists N=\mathcal{N}(\epsilon,x)\gt0,\,n\ge N \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon \\ \\
&\text{Uniformly Convergent on $[a,b]$}\iff \\
&\forall x\in [a,b]\,\forall\epsilon\gt0\,\exists N=\mathcal{N}(\epsilon)\gt0,\quad\, n\ge N \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon.
\end{align*}

So the difference is that in PWC the number $N$ depends on $x$ while in UC it does not which means just one $N$ works for all $x$ in $[a,b]$.

I want to prove the following theorem.

> **Theorem**. If the functions $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous at $x_0\in[a,b]$ and their sequence converges uniformly to the function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

**Proof**. According to the definition of continuity at $x_0$ for $f$, we want to show that

\begin{align*}
\forall\epsilon\gt0\,\exists \delta=\Delta(\epsilon,x_0)\gt0,\,|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon.
\end{align*}

According to triangle inequality we have

\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le|f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|.
\tag{1}
\end{align*}

If we could control each of the three terms on the RHS of $(1)$ such that they were less than $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ then the theorem was proved. According to the assumptions we know that the following holds

\begin{align*}
&\forall\epsilon_1\gt0\,\exists \delta_1=\Delta_1(\epsilon_1,x_0,n)\gt0,\,|x-x_0|<\delta_1 \implies |f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\epsilon_1 \\
\\
&\forall x\in [a,b]\,\forall\epsilon_2\gt0\,\exists N=\mathcal{N}(\epsilon_2)\gt0, n\ge N \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon_2.
\end{align*}
Finally, choosing any $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ such that $0<\epsilon_1\le\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and $0<\epsilon_2\le\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and setting any $\delta$ such that $\delta\le\delta_1$ will do the job. For simplicity, one can usually take the equality cases which means $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and $\delta=\delta_1$.

$1$. Is my proof OK? Any suggestions for improvement is really appreciated.

$2$. Are the notations $\mathcal{N}(\epsilon,x)$ or $\Delta(\epsilon,x,n)$ OK? I just employed them to emphasize the the dependence on $\epsilon$ and $x$. Any better suggestion is welcomed.

$3$. I was wondering which step would fail if we just had PWC? An example can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notations and proof seem great, and why the condition PWC is not sufficient is that under this you cannot choose your $\mathcal{N}(\epsilon_2)$ feasible for any $x$ in your domain. (Maybe for arbitrarily large $N$ there always exist some $x$ near $x_0$ making your argument fail.)

Comment: Thanks. :) Is there any weaker condition than uniform convergence on $[a,b]$. For example, can't we say that $f_n$ be uniformly convergent in some neighborhood of $x_0$? I don't know maybe some notion like locally uniform convergent or something may still work.