# Why $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$ on $[0,1]$ doesn't converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I was solving this problem:

> For the following {$f_n$} sequence, determine the pointwise limit of {$f_n$} (if it exists) on the invterval, and indicate if {$f_n$} converges uniformly towards this function.$$f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}, on [0,1]$$

I ended up with the pointwise limit being $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{1/n}=1$ if $0<x\leq  1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{1/n}=0$ if $x=0$. My problem is to determine if it does or doesn't converge uniformly, I saw a question about it on this website, but I didn't understand it. The answer was that it doesn't converge uniformly, can you explain me why? Thanks.

Comment: read through the definition of uniform convergence

Comment: What is the limit of $f_n(x)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$? Is it continuous on [0,1]?

Comment: @TheoC. it's not helpful, because that's (continuity of limiting function) not the definition of uniform convergence (but merely a consequence).

Comment: The limit is $0$ if $x=0$ and $1$ if $0<x\leq 1$, so it isn't continous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @TheoC. if you're implying this is my question, then be aware it's not, if you don't (I can't quite interprete this), how is it apparent that if limit is not continuous, then convergence is not uniform? It needs to be proved somehow (perhaps handwavy).

Comment: @enedil A common result of uniform convergence is that continuity is preserved in the limit. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425866/uniform-convergence-preserves-continuity . As such, if one can show that the limiting function isn't continuous somewhere on $[0,1]$ (namely not continuous at $0$) then we have shown that the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: @SeanNemetz I read it, but I don't see the problem.

Comment: @TheoC. yes, I know it, but as you probably see, question author doesn't have such intuition.

Comment: The pointwise limit  function is not continuous. If a sequence of functions converges uniformly  to a function $f$, then $f$ is also the pointwise limit. So if we were to assume that the given sequence of functions converge uniformly, then the Uniform Limit Theorem would say that the pointwise limit is continuous which is an obvious contradiction.

Comment: Show we can't find $N$ that does not depend on $x$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x) | < \epsilon$ for $n > N$ and for ALL $x \in (0,1]$.

Comment: Or show we can't find $N$ such that $|f_n(x)-f_{2n}(x)|<\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac12$ whenever $n>N$ and $x \in [0,1]$ which would show that the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is not uniformly Cauchy on $[0,1]$. If a sequence converges, then it is Cauchy...

Comment: Ok, I understand now why it doesn't converge uniformly. Now, how do I show that we can't find such $N$? I find those epsilon-delta definitions pretty hard.

Comment: Select $\varepsilon=\frac12$, or rather $\varepsilon=\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac12$. Let $N \in \mathbb N$ be given. So $2^{-N} \in (0,1]$ but $|1-f_N(2^{-N})|=\frac12$, or rather $|f_N(2^{-N})-f_{2N}(2^{-N})|=\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac12$.

Comment: I don't undestand. Where does the $2^{-N}$ comes from?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$|1 -f_n(2^{-n})| = \frac{1}{2} \not\to 0$$

Comment: I don't understand what you did there. Where does that $f_n(2^{-n})$ comes from?

Comment: The limit is $f(x) = 1$ for $0 < x \leqslant 1$ and $f(0) = 0$.  For uniform convergence we must have for any $\epsilon > 0$, $N(\epsilon)$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)|< \epsilon$ for all $n > N$ and for all $x \in (0,1]$.  Take $\epsilon = 1/4$ say.  So if $x \neq 0$ we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = 1 - x^{1/n}$ But for any $n$ no matter how large if we look at $x = 2^{-n}$ we get $1 - (2^{-n})^{1/n} = 1/2$ and this is not less than $1/4$.

Comment: I see. You choose $x=2^{-n}$ for convenience, right? In the case that $x=0$, it woudl be $|0-x^{1/n}| right?

Comment: Yes it was a convenient choice.  We don't need to worry about $0$ where convergence is automatic since $f_n(0) = f(0) = 0$.  It is points near $0$ in $(0,1]$ that cause problems.  If $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ then it converges uniformly on $(0,1]$.  So if it fails to converge uniformly on $(0,1]$ that is enough to show.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What other $x$ could I choose?

Comment: Any sequence $x_n \in (0,1]$ where $x_n^{1/n}$ does not converge to $1$. So $2^{-n}$, $3^{-n}$, $(\pi/4)^{-n}$, etc. They all have the property that $|1 - x_n^{1/n}|$ stays bigger than some positive number.

Comment: Can't I choose $\frac{1}{2}$? The fact that w chose a number raised to ${-n}$ isn't necessary, right?

Comment: Take $\varepsilon=\frac12$. $\sup_{x \in (0,1]} |1-f_n(x)|\geq |1-f_n(2^{-n})|=\frac12$. The definition of uniform convergence says $"<\varepsilon"$, and the negation of this is $"\geq \varepsilon"$ (greater than or equal to). So taking $\varepsilon=\frac12$ works in showing that the negation of the definition of uniform convergence is satisfied when we consider the set of points $\{2^{-n}: n \in \mathbb N \}$. When considering the set of points $\{r^{n}: n \in \mathbb N\}$, to some extent it does matter what number $r \in (0,1)$ we choose to use. Ie; $|1-f_n(\frac23^n)|=\frac13<\frac12$.